# trying to get id of associated name value from json

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

```
$(function () {
var availableData = [{
    "Name": "bob barker",
    "image": "./images/bbarker.png"
    "id":"bob"
}, {
    "Name": "Jill bill",
    "image": "./images/jBill.png"
    "id":"jill"
}, {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "image": "./images/jdoe.png"
    "id":"john"
}]

$('#personsearch').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
        response($.grep(($.map(availableData, function (v, i) {

            return {
                label: v.Name,
                value: v.Name
            };
        })), function (item) {
            return matcher.test(item.value);
        }))

    }
});
});
```

---

```
    <input type="text" id="personsearch" value="?????" />
    <input type ="submit"/>
```

I am trying to get the id in the input field for submit purpose means the associated id is come with the name and the id value is filled in value="?????" how to do that please help

Comment: U want to fill multiple textboxes with json data in foreach?

Comment: no I want only one text box but the values are associated according to filled name in the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the select event of autocomplete to populate the name attribute after selecting a value.

```
$('#personsearch').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
        response($.grep(($.map(availableData, function (v, i) {

            return {

                label: v.id,
                value: v.Name

            };
            $("#personsearch").attr("name", value)
        })), function (item) {

            return matcher.test(item.value);
        }))

    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#personsearch').attr("name", $(this).val());
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDC69/12/)